# /usr/bin/pip3 does not install package globally when in venv. How to do it?

Tags: python, linux, ansible, python-venv

After creating and activating a virtual environment:

```sh
python3 -m venv env
. ./env/bin/activate
```

the global `/usr/bin/pip3` does not install a package globally. Actually it does copy package files but package is not fully installed:

```sh
 /usr/bin/pip3 install docker
Collecting docker
  Downloading docker-5.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 146 kB 2.5 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from docker) (2.22.0)
Collecting websocket-client>=0.32.0
  Downloading websocket_client-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 52 kB 2.9 MB/s 
Installing collected packages: websocket-client, docker
Successfully installed docker-5.0.3 websocket-client-1.2.1
```

Files are placed globally:

```sh
ls /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages
docker  docker-5.0.3.dist-info  websocket  websocket_client-1.2.1.dist-info
```

But neither a shell without venv active doesn't consider docker as installed:

```sh
pip3 list|grep docker
python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docker'
>>>
```

nor the venv sees docker package as installed:

```sh
(env) pip3 list|grep docker
(env) python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docker'
>>>
```

**Is this a bug?**

**How can I install a package globally with pip3 while a venv is active?**

Why do I want to do this?

Ansible is launched from a venv and it targets the localhost. So if I'm using just `pip3` as an executable, it uses the binary from the venv. If I'm using `/usr/bin/pip3` I get the above behavior.

It's a more complex open source project and I don't have the option to not run Ansible from a venv or not to target localhost.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I don't use venv myself, but the whole point of virtual environments is having a set of files separated from the rest of the system.

If you create a virtual environment and are inside of it you shouldn't be using `/usr/bin/pip3`, you should be using the default `pip3`, since those two versions might not even be compatible with each other.~

> It's a more complex open source project and I don't have the option to not run Ansible from a venv

You always have the option of running something inside a virtual environment, it might happen that the program does not respect that and use global paths and ignore that virtual environment, which shouldn't be happening.

From the venv docs:

> Each virtual environment has its own Python binary (which matches the version of the binary that was used to create this environment) and can have its own independent set of installed Python packages in its site directories

This means that you should create your virtual environment, activate it, install whatever you want inside of it, and then run everything inside that virtual environment.

So I don't see this as a bug, it just seems like you are not using as it is intended to be used. If you want something installed globally, why are you using a virtual environment in the first place?

Comment: I think you missed the point. I know what a venv is for.

Comment: Then what is it exactly you are trying to do?